# Componente DBTreeGrid para o DelphiXE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Estou precisando de um componente `DBTreeGrid` para o `DelphiXE3`? Já procurei no Google mas não encontrei nada :(

Alguém conhece algum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suite DevExpress tem o `dxDBTreeList`.

Um exemplo pode ser visto neste link https://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumTreeList/